# skaffold and microk8s -- container server is waiting to start: <image> can't be pulled

Tags: docker, kubernetes, microk8s, skaffold

I'm hitting this error on a unbuntu 20.04 installation, with microk8s and skaffold.

```
container server is waiting to start: aliwatters/dkc-multi-server:7b9b7d87ab81483cdb9b1227780d68dec815fe271aea2f9fe3a0e65090d90909 can't be pulled
```

I'm logged into docker.

Full error is

```
exiting dev mode because first deploy failed: 1/1 deployment(s) failed
ali@stinky:~/git/dkc-multi-k8s (feature-skaffold-minimal)$ skaffold dev
Listing files to watch...
 - aliwatters/dkc-multi-server
Generating tags...
 - aliwatters/dkc-multi-server -> aliwatters/dkc-multi-server:90d1283
Checking cache...
 - aliwatters/dkc-multi-server: Found Locally
Tags used in deployment:
 - aliwatters/dkc-multi-server -> aliwatters/dkc-multi-server:7b9b7d87ab81483cdb9b1227780d68dec815fe271aea2f9fe3a0e65090d90909
Starting deploy...
 - service/server-cluster-ip-service created
 - deployment.apps/server-deployment created
Waiting for deployments to stabilize...
 - deployment/server-deployment: creating container server
    - pod/server-deployment-5f496cf9c7-8dfp8: creating container server
    - pod/server-deployment-5f496cf9c7-hzc2l: creating container server
    - pod/server-deployment-5f496cf9c7-2mn6x: container server is waiting to start: aliwatters/dkc-multi-server:7b9b7d87ab81483cdb9b1227780d68dec815fe271aea2f9fe3a0e65090d90909 can't be pulled
 - deployment/server-deployment failed. Error: creating container server.
Cleaning up...
 - service "server-cluster-ip-service" deleted
 - deployment.apps "server-deployment" deleted
exiting dev mode because first deploy failed: 1/1 deployment(s) failed
```

All the relevant files;

```
ali@stinky:~/git/dkc-multi-k8s (feature-skaffold-minimal)$ cat skaffold.yaml 
apiVersion: skaffold/v2beta11
kind: Config
build:
  artifacts:
    - image: aliwatters/dkc-multi-server
      context: server
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      sync:
        manual:
        - src: '**/*.js'
          dest: .
  local:
    push: false
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
      - k8s/server-cluster-ip-service.yaml
      - k8s/server-deployment.yaml

ali@stinky:~/git/dkc-multi-k8s (feature-skaffold-minimal)$ cat k8s/server-deployment.yaml 
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: server-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: server
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: server
          image: aliwatters/dkc-multi-server
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5000
          env:
            - name: REDIS_HOST
              value: redis-cluster-ip-service
            - name: REDIS_PORT
              value: '6379'
            - name: PGUSER
              value: postgres
            - name: PGHOST
              value: postgres-cluster-ip-service
            - name: PGPORT
              value: '5432'
            - name: PGDATABASE
              value: postgres
            - name: PGPASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: pgpasswd
                  key: PGPASSWORD

ali@stinky:~/git/dkc-multi-k8s (feature-skaffold-minimal)$ cat k8s/server-cluster-ip-service.yaml 
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: server-cluster-ip-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    component: server
  ports:
    - port: 5000
      targetPort: 5000
```

And the microk8s config

```
ali@stinky:~/git/dkc-multi-k8s (feature-skaffold-minimal)$ more ~/.kube/config 
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBDRVJUSUZJQ0FURS0tLS0tCk1JSURBVENDQWVtZ0F3SUJBZ0lKQUx
aR3B0NDZ... snip ..EhqYThFZjBsMzVFdmxFa1pJeGpwOHh5NEVLUHMKTFpCbDB3TT0KLS0tLS1FTkQgQ0VSV
ElGSUNBVEUtLS0tLQo=
    server: https://127.0.0.1:16443
  name: microk8s-cluster
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: microk8s-cluster
    user: admin
  name: microk8s
current-context: microk8s
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: admin
  user:
    token: VDlqa3BnWlR4Q3UzaHhpQnFvamlkbDdBRk9aMzdBcDkvMFhZT21ad1VqND0K
```

Versions

```
ali@stinky:~/git/dkc-multi-k8s (feature-skaffold-minimal)$ snap list
Name                  Version                     Rev    Tracking         Publisher    Notes
kubectl               1.20.2                      1811   latest/stable    canonical✓   classic
microk8s              v1.20.1                     1910   1.20/stable      canonical✓   classic

ali@stinky:~/git/dkc-multi-k8s (feature-skaffold-minimal)$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20+", GitVersion:"v1.20.1-34+e7db93d188d0d1", GitCommit:"e7db93d188d0d12f2fe5336d1b85cdb94cb909d3", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-01-11T23:48:42Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.6", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20+", GitVersion:"v1.20.1-34+e7db93d188d0d1", GitCommit:"e7db93d188d0d12f2fe5336d1b85cdb94cb909d3", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-01-11T23:50:46Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.6", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

ali@stinky:~/git/dkc-multi-k8s (feature-skaffold-minimal)$ skaffold version
v1.18.0
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try to [Create a Secret based on existing Docker credentials](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/#registry-secret-existing-credentials) and [Create a Pod that uses your Secret](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/#create-a-pod-that-uses-your-secret)

Comment: Thanks Matt, I ran through those, skeptically -- as this is a not a private image, no change. https://hub.docker.com/repository/registry-1.docker.io/aliwatters/dkc-multi-server/tags?page=1&ordering=last_updated -- notice that the tag asked for by skaffold isn't present.

Comment: https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold/issues/5327 -- turns out that at this moment in time microk8s is not fully supported by skaffold. (seeing if I can fix that)

Answer (score 0):

This happens because `MicroK8s` doesn't see the images which were built by your local `Docker` daemon. The final solution to this problem is being discussed in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold/issues/5327).

For the moment, you can solve the problem by importing your images into `MicroK8s`:

```bash
docker save myimage > myimage.tar;
microk8s ctr image import myimage.tar;
```

If you prefer a global solution, you can start [`MicroK8s` built-in registry](https://microk8s.io/docs/registry-built-in) with `microk8s enable registry`. This will expose as a `NodePort` service on port `32000` of the `localhost`.

Then run your `Skaffold` commands with [default-repo functionality](https://skaffold.dev/docs/environment/image-registries/) by using `--default-repo` or just `-d`:

```bash
skaffold run -d localhost:32000
```